# How to update input field according to a value of select field using React.js with Formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am building an app displays different phone number format according to a country that I selected using Formik and libphonenumber.js library.

Here is the code:

```
  const selectCountry = (e:any, phoneNumber:string) => {
    const countryPhoneNumberFormat = new AsYouType(e.target.value).input(phoneNumber)
    console.log(countryPhoneNumberFormat)
    // KR -> 012-2934-2937
    // SR -> 0123-9342

  }

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{country: '', phoneNumber: ''}} onSubmit={(values) => submitForm(values)}>
      {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <select name='country' onChange={(e) => selectCountry(e, values.phoneNumber)}>
          <option value=''>Country</option>
          <option value='KR'>Korea</option>
          <option value='SG'>Singapore</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='phoneNumber' placeholder={'Enter your phone number'} value={values.phoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '50%'}} />
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
```

So when I select either Korea or Singapore in select field, **selectCountry** function will read the change, and using **new AsYouType** from libphonenumber.js library, I can format the phoneNumber.

I used useState in React Hook to change the state and placed it inside of **phoneNumber input value** but seems like Formik does not read state changes outside of Formik.

Is there a way I can make phoneNumber input read and display **countryPhoneNumberFormat** variable inside of **selectCountry** function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either Formiks `handleChange` or `setFieldValue` method in your `onChange` function. It could work like this:

```
  const selectCountry = (e:any, phoneNumber:string) => {
    return new AsYouType(e.target.value).input(phoneNumber);
  }

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{country: '', phoneNumber: ''}} onSubmit={(values) => submitForm(values)}>
      {({ values, handleChange, handleSubmit }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <select name='country' 
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setFieldValue('phoneNumber', selectCountry(e, values.phoneNumber));
                }
        }>
          <option value=''>Country</option>
          <option value='KR'>Korea</option>
          <option value='SG'>Singapore</option>
        </select>
        <input type='text' name='phoneNumber' placeholder={'Enter your phone number'} value={values.phoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} style={{width: '50%'}} />
        </form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  )
```

As soon as you select a certain country the form value of `phoneNumber` will be set to the return value of `selectCountry`.